# Getting "InternalError: no such savepoint" with PostGIS in Django even when using TransactionTestCase

Tags: django, unit-testing, geodjango

Just added geoDjango and moved the database over to PostGIS. I have a bunch of Unit tests that pass individually, but when run together I get an IntenalError the database being grumpy between the tests. The model that's getting used in these tests is a django.contrib.gis.db model. The tests even inherit from TransactionTestCase instead of the regular TestCase class. Same situation for both. Funny thing is, when I switch back to MySQL they all run just fine. But I can't stay on MySQL because I need to write distance queries next.

How do I automate these tests in geoDjango with postgres? What do I do?

---

P.S. YES: I have the settings.py stuff:

```
DATABASE_ENGINE = 'postgresql_psycopg2'
.....
TEST_RUNNER='django.contrib.gis.tests.run_tests'
POSTGIS_TEMPLATE='template_postgis'
POSTGIS_SQL_PATH='/usr/share/postgresql-8.3-postgis/'
```

here's the stack trace:

```
..EEE
======================================================================
ERROR: a valid address should yeild redirect to the profile page
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 242, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 217, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 222, in _fixture_setup
    call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 166, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/flush.py", line 61, in handle_noargs
    emit_post_sync_signal(models.get_models(), verbosity, interactive)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 205, in emit_post_sync_signal
    interactive=interactive)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 166, in send
    response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/__init__.py", line 28, in create_permissions
    defaults={'name': name, 'content_type': ctype})
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 123, in get_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 339, in get_or_create
    transaction.savepoint_rollback(sid)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 199, in savepoint_rollback
    connection._savepoint_rollback(sid)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 67, in _savepoint_rollback
    self.cursor().execute(self.ops.savepoint_rollback_sql(sid))
InternalError: no such savepoint


======================================================================
ERROR: test_repair_types (rubbercan_profiles.tests.test_view.TestProfileView)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 242, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 217, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 222, in _fixture_setup
    call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 166, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/flush.py", line 31, in handle_noargs
    sql_list = sql_flush(self.style, only_django=True)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 128, in sql_flush
    tables = connection.introspection.django_table_names(only_existing=True)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 510, in django_table_names
    tables = [t for t in tables if self.table_name_converter(t) in self.table_names()]
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 491, in table_names
    return self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/introspection.py", line 30, in get_table_list
    AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)""")
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block


======================================================================
ERROR: test_zip_code_length (rubbercan_profiles.tests.test_view.TestProfileView)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 242, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 217, in _pre_setup
    self._fixture_setup()
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 222, in _fixture_setup
    call_command('flush', verbosity=0, interactive=False)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 166, in call_command
    return klass.execute(*args, **defaults)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 222, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/flush.py", line 31, in handle_noargs
    sql_list = sql_flush(self.style, only_django=True)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.py", line 128, in sql_flush
    tables = connection.introspection.django_table_names(only_existing=True)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 510, in django_table_names
    tables = [t for t in tables if self.table_name_converter(t) in self.table_names()]
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/__init__.py", line 491, in table_names
    return self.get_table_list(cursor)
  File "/home/hendrixski/rubvirtenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/introspection.py", line 30, in get_table_list
    AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)""")
InternalError: current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 24.592s
```

and here are the unit tests:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.test import TransactionTestCase
from django.test.client import Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from geopy import geocoders
from exceptions import ValueError, KeyError
from rubbercan_profiles.forms import ProfileForm
from rubbercan_profiles.models import Profile
from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.gis.maps.google import GoogleMap, GMarker

class TestProfileView(TransactionTestCase):
    fixtures = ['test_rc_profiles.json']

    def setUp(self):
        self.c = Client()
        self.c.login(username="asdf", password="asdf")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.c.logout()

    def test_repair_types(self):
        """ 
        Verify that the repair types are being accessed properly from the templates and displayed properly
        """
        #verify the setup is what we expect
        u1 = User.objects.get(username="asdf")
        self.assertTrue("Collision repair" in u1.get_profile().repair_types)
        #it should display on the page as well        
        response = self.c.get(reverse("profile_detail", args=['asdf']))
        self.assertContains(response, "Collision repair")


    def test_zip_code_length(self):
        """ 
        For some reason min_value and min_length didn't work on the model field. 
        So  we have our own form validator that makes sure the length of the zipcode is long enough, 
        and that it's not too long. In a perfect world, we could identify whether the zipcode exists or not,
        but we do not do this yet. 
        """
        #empty input
        response=self.c.post(reverse("profile_edit"), {"name": "Barnaby", "zipCode": ""})
        self.assertFormError(response, 'profile_form', 'zipCode', [u'This field is required.'])

        #too short input
        response=self.c.post(reverse("profile_edit"), {"name": "Barnaby", "zipCode": 941})
        self.assertFormError(response, 'profile_form', 'zipCode', [u'Please enter a valid zipcode.'])


    def test_bad_geocoding(self):
        """
        When a bad address is passed to the form, it should indicate the error at the top of the form.
        in the forms NON_FIELD_ERRORS
        """
        badZipCode = 99916
        g = geocoders.Google(settings.GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY)
        self.assertRaises(ValueError, g.geocode, badZipCode)
        response=self.c.post(reverse("profile_edit"), {"name": "Barnaby", "zipCode": badZipCode})
        self.assertContains(response, "Please enter a valid address")

        response=self.c.post(reverse("profile_edit"), {"name": "Barnaby", "street": "2311 23nd Ave", 
                                                       "city": "San Francisco", "state": "CA", "zipCode": badZipCode})
        self.assertContains(response, "Please enter a valid address")        
        #TODO check that the non_field_errors are getting it

    def test_good_geocoding(self):
        "a valid address should yeild redirect to the profile page"
        response=self.c.post(reverse("profile_edit"), {"street": "2311 32nd Ave", "city": "San Francisco",
                                                       "name": "barnaby", "state": "CA", "zipCode": 94116})
        self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("profile_detail", args=['asdf']), 302)


    def context_lookup(self, response, key):
        "Stupid hack for 1.0.3 backwards compatability"
        # used for debugging
        for subcontext in response.context:
            if key in subcontext:
                return subcontext[key]
        raise KeyError


    def test_gmap(self):
        """
        Shops should pass a google maps item to the template, so that we can display their 
        location for customers to see.
        Customers should NOT pass a google map into their template
        """
        #assuming bob is a shop and has a point, he gets a map
        bobCheck = Profile.objects.get(id=1)
        assert bobCheck.point is not None
        self.assertEqual(bobCheck.status, Profile.REPAIR_SHOP)
        response = self.c.get(reverse("profile_detail", args=['bob']))
        assert isinstance(self.context_lookup(response, 'google'), GoogleMap)


        #assuming joe is not a shop, his profile doesn't show a map
        joeCheck = Profile.objects.get(id=2)
        self.assertEqual(joeCheck.status, Profile.CUSTOMER)
        response = self.c.get(reverse("profile_detail", args=['joe']))
        self.assertRaises( KeyError, self.context_lookup, response, 'google')

        #assuming asdf is a shop, but doesn't have a point, 
        #when he views his profile he should be prompted about his profile being incomplete
        asdfCheck = Profile.objects.get(id=3)
        assert asdfCheck.point is None
        self.assertEqual(asdfCheck.status, Profile.REPAIR_SHOP)
        response = self.c.get(reverse("profile_detail", args=['asdf']))
        self.assertRaises(KeyError, self.context_lookup, response, 'google')
        self.assertContains(response, "incomplete")
```

And, here is what the postgres log looks like:

```
hendrixski@hendrixski:/var/log$ tail -60 pgsql 
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [142-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "auth_permission" ("name", "content_type_id", "codename") VALUES (E'Can
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [142-2]  delete group', 2, E'delete_group')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [143-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: SELECT CURRVAL('"auth_permission_id_seq"')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [144-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: COMMIT
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [145-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [146-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: SELECT "auth_permission"."id", "auth_permission"."name",
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [146-2]  "auth_permission"."content_type_id", "auth_permission"."codename" FROM "auth_permission" INNER JOIN "django_content_type" ON
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [146-3]  ("auth_permission"."content_type_id" = "django_content_type"."id") WHERE ("auth_permission"."codename" = E'add_user'  AND
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [146-4]  "auth_permission"."content_type_id" = 3 ) ORDER BY "django_content_type"."app_label" ASC, "auth_permission"."codename" ASC
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [147-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: SAVEPOINT s1217292608_x1
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [148-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "auth_permission" ("name", "content_type_id", "codename") VALUES (E'Can add
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [148-2]  user', 3, E'add_user')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [149-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: SELECT CURRVAL('"auth_permission_id_seq"')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [150-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: COMMIT
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [151-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST ERROR:  insert or update on table "auth_permission" violates foreign key constraint
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [151-2]  "content_type_id_refs_id_728de91f"
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [151-3] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id)=(3) is not present in table "django_content_type".
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [151-4] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST STATEMENT:  COMMIT
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [152-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [153-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT s1217292608_x1
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [154-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST ERROR:  no such savepoint
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [154-2] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST STATEMENT:  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT s1217292608_x1
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [155-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: 
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [155-2] #011            SELECT c.relname
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [155-3] #011            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [155-4] #011            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [155-5] #011            WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v', '')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [155-6] #011                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [155-7] #011                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [156-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [156-2] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST STATEMENT:  
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [156-3] #011            SELECT c.relname
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [156-4] #011            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [156-5] #011            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [156-6] #011            WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v', '')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [156-7] #011                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [156-8] #011                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [157-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: 
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [157-2] #011            SELECT c.relname
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [157-3] #011            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [157-4] #011            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [157-5] #011            WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v', '')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [157-6] #011                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [157-7] #011                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [158-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST ERROR:  current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [158-2] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST STATEMENT:  
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [158-3] #011            SELECT c.relname
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [158-4] #011            FROM pg_catalog.pg_class c
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [158-5] #011            LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [158-6] #011            WHERE c.relkind IN ('r', 'v', '')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [158-7] #011                AND n.nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'pg_toast')
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [158-8] #011                AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(c.oid)
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13506]: [159-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13507]: [3-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: SET DATESTYLE TO 'ISO'
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13507]: [4-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: SHOW client_encoding
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13507]: [5-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: SHOW default_transaction_isolation
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13507]: [6-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: BEGIN; SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13507]: [7-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: SET TIME ZONE E'US/Eastern'
Feb 11 12:57:51 hendrixski postgres[13507]: [8-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:51 PST LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
Feb 11 12:57:52 hendrixski postgres[13507]: [9-1] 2010-02-11 12:57:52 PST LOG:  statement: DROP DATABASE "test_rubbercan"
```

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this helps somebody save a lot of time! I found the culprit!  A separate application for reviews: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-reviews/0.2.1

I'm going to try contacting the author and further diagnosing this, maybe getting it fixed.

Man that was a lot of work.